# Is there a name prop for an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, methods

```
$(()=>{
alert( $.name )
})
```

> The above jQuery code alert **k**
> Why?

Comment: js functions always have 'name' property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Answer (score 3):

Every function in JavaScript has a `name` property.

```js
function myFunction ()  {}
console.log(myFunction.name)
const $ = myFunction
console.log($.name)
```

Answer (score 3):

> The above jQuery code alert k Why?

Functions automatically get a name property. The fact that it's `k` specifically is just luck. The code is being run through a [minifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) to make it as short as possible, and by chance the minified code used `k` in defining window.$.

```js
window.$ = function k() {};
console.log($.name);
```